# Why doesn't the dart compiler not detect an error in this line of code? The variable type is clearly a boolean

Tags: flutter, dart

Look out for the comment written 'error is here'. The compiler should throw an error if the types don't match, but it doesn't. The variable type is a boolean and I have passed in a string as the value. As such, their should be an error thrown that the types do not match.

```
class CompanyPreferences {
  late bool editHistory;
  late bool showOrderReference;
  late bool canBeOffline;
  late bool hasCancel;
  late bool hasSkip;
  late bool homepagePickup;
  late double geofenceDistance;
  late bool viewPendingOrders;

  CompanyPreferences({
    this.editHistory = true,
    this.showOrderReference = false,
    this.canBeOffline = false,
    this.hasCancel = true,
    this.hasSkip = true,
    this.homepagePickup = false,
    this.geofenceDistance = 0.0,
    this.viewPendingOrders = false,
  });

  factory CompanyPreferences.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return CompanyPreferences(
      editHistory: map["preference_data"]["driver_app"] == null ? true : map["preference_data"]["driver_app"]['edit_history'] ?? true,
      showOrderReference: map["preference_data"]["driver_app"] == null ? false : map["preference_data"]["driver_app"]['show_order_reference'] ?? false,
      canBeOffline: map["preference_data"]["driver_app"] == null ? false : map["preference_data"]["driver_app"]['can_be_offline'] ?? false,
      hasCancel: map["preference_data"]["driver_app"] == null ? false : map["preference_data"]["driver_app"]['has_cancel'] ?? false,
      hasSkip: map["preference_data"]["driver_app"] == null ? false : map["preference_data"]["driver_app"]['has_skip'] ?? false,
      homepagePickup: map["preference_data"]["driver_app"] == null ? false : map["preference_data"]["driver_app"]['homepage_pickup'] ?? false,
      geofenceDistance: map["preference_data"]["driver_app"] == null
          ? 0.0
          : map["preference_data"]["driver_app"]['geofence_distance'] == null
              ? 0.0
              : map["preference_data"]["driver_app"]['geofence_distance'].toDouble(),
// Error is here. The compiler doesn't throw an error.
      viewPendingOrders: map["preference_data"]["driver_app"] == null ? "ERROR IS HERE" : map["preference_data"]["driver_app"]['view_pending_orders'] ?? false,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distilling your problem down a bit:

```dart
Type staticType<T>(T object) => T;

void main() {
  var map = <String, dynamic>{};
  var x = map['foo'] == null ? 'string' : map['bar'] ?? false;
  print(staticType(x)); // Prints: dynamic
}
```

The problem is that `map['bar']` has type `dynamic` and basically poisons the rest of the conditional ternary expression.

The "then" part of the conditional expression is of type `String`, and the "else" part has a `??` expression.  The result of that `??` expression can either be the `dynamic` type on the left side or the `bool` type on the right.  The `??` expression thus is determined to have a static type of the nearest common base type of `dynamic` and `bool`, which is `dynamic`.  Similarly, the type of the conditional ternary expression will be the nearest common base type of `String` and `dynamic`, which again will be `dynamic`.

Since the entire conditional ternary expression will be of type `dynamic`, it will not be type-checked when passing it as a `bool` argument.